# Query $sum of range of values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have the following mongodb collection called Expenses.

```
description |   date    | value |
Parking Lot  2017-02-22    10
McDonalds    2017-03-01    50
BurgerKing   2017-03-12    100
Parking Lot  2017-03-21    15
```

I want to **query with a range of dates**, like from 2017-03-01 to 2017-03-31 **and get only the sum of the value field**.

Comment: Try filtering documents using `$match` stage followed by `$group` stage with `$sum` accumlator on `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Expenses.aggregate([
{$match:{"date":{$gte:ISODate("2017-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
                 $lte:ISODate("2017-03-31T00:00:00Z")}}},
{$group:{_id:null, sumvalue:{$sum:"$value"}}}
]);
```